# selenium execution is slow

Tags: linux, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Recently I transferred all my tests to a new server. I observed that just page navigation to some pages are taking more time such as 15 sec. I am not sure whether it is Selenium or Test server issue. Any suggestions

My old server:
 LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: SUSE LINUX
Description:    openSUSE 11.4 (x86_64)
Release:        11.4
Codename:       Celadon

Selenium: 2.43, Firefox 29

New server:
LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: openSUSE project
Description:    openSUSE 13.2 (Harlequin) (x86_64)
Release:        13.2
Codename:       Harlequin

Selenium: 2.53 , Firefox 45

Comment: It hs nothing to do with Selenium, Please use load testing.

Comment: So what I did is : In my old server :
I installed Selenium 2.53 and Firefox 45
Tried opening google.co.in url and it worked . But when I use firefox profile I am getting below error


 Failed to retrieve Firefox Driver - Exception: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /home/xxx/tmpDyaAPO/tmpDxR6nD/webdriver-py-profilecopy If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.

I extracted with sudo permissions and chmod all files under Firefox profile to 777.

Comment: Next I tried with Firefox 46. When I set PATH variable to firefox 46 I am getting below error

XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /home/vvooda/Firefox46/firefox/libmozgtk.so:
libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.

This one too extracted with sudo permissions and chmod all files under Firefox profile to 777.

Any suggestions...

Comment: Now I downloaded firefox 47.0.1 . Some forums mentioned Selenium 2.5.3.1 is compatible with Firefox 47.0.1
But I am getting below error 
Failed to retrieve Firefox Driver - Exception: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir:....
tmpV5_Q5U/webdriver-py-profilecopy If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.

I suppose this is related to permission. Anyone has faced the issue and how they fixed it?

Comment: Venu, Please add new question if issue is different, make sure your search SO first before adding new question

Comment: Its not a new question. In every comment I am making progress. but if any suggestions pls share - is it related to any permissions wrt Linux. Because normal GU samples like google pages are automated. Only pages having SSL need firefox profile to by pass them. Yes firefox profile is also used for other uses.